# OpenGL 3.3 on Mac OSX El Capitan with LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I am currently trying to create an OpenGL 3.3 context in LWJGL 3 on my Macbook Pro mid 2014. My sourcecode to initialize the window looks like this:

```
if (!glfwInit()) {
    Logger.addError("GLFW", "init failed");
}

glfwDefaultWindowHints();

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);           
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE, GL_TRUE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

// glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 2);

ID = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title, 0, 0);
if (ID == 0) {
    Logger.addError("GLFW", "window creation failed");
}
```

Sadly GLFW fails to create the window for any version higher than 2.1, the version `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returns when leaving out the window hints ... 
I read through all of the "duplicate" questions, but as you can see I already request core profile and forward compatibility. Moreover I installed XCode and have the newest version of the operating system. Do you guys have any other suggestions or did I understand anything horribly wrong? 
Thanks in advance...

Note that there is no `"GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE"` flag in LWJGL 3 afaik, so I can't copy the code from the official GLFW getting started page 1:1. Setting the `"GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE"` flag to true worked on windows though thus this cant be the error making trouble...

Comment: Are you sure your GPU supports core OpenGL?

Comment: Which version of OS X are you using? Earlier versions only support OpenGL up to 2.1.

Comment: As I said: I use a fairly new MacBook Pro 13" Retina from mid 2014 with the latest update of OSX El Capitan. Acoording to Apple it should support OpenGL up to version 4.1, but I cant figure out how...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are setting the core profile window hint is incorrect. Instead use:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

From the [GLFW documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html#window_hints_ctx):

> `GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE` specifies which OpenGL profile to create the context for. Possible values are one of `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE` or `GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE`, or `GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE` to not request a specific profile. If requesting an OpenGL version below 3.2, `GLFW_OPENGL_ANY_PROFILE` must be used. If OpenGL ES is requested, this hint is ignored.

Comment: Well you can correct me, but there is no GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE flag in LWJGL... This is what I meant with I cant copy the GLFW documentation 1:1

Comment: Weird, it's included in the [JavaDoc](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW.html#GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE) though. Are you using the official LWJGL 3.0.0 release?

Comment: Try setting a GLFW error callback like described in the [LWJGL 3 migration guide](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/2.6.6-LWJGL3-migration).

Comment: I am so sorry. You are 100% right. I thought I did my homework with reading through all the docs and similiar questions, but didnt recognize I was initializing the window wrong, because it always worked on Windows. The reason why I could not find the 'GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE' flag is as simple and embarassing as this: instead of using  'import ...GLFW.*;' Eclipse changed it to individual imports. I did not notice that and thought the flag was missing, because it was not highlited by auto complete... Again: I am really sorry for all of this and really appreciate your help.. Thank you so much!

Comment: @PrudiiArca No problem, this happens to the best of us.