# ContextAttribs(3, 2, CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB) does not work for me on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, opengl, lwjgl

Tried making a game using lwjgl, I needed to use `GL33` for something, so tried changing `ContextAttribs(3,2)` to `(3,3)` but that lead to a lot of errors, cause on osx this will change your open gl version 4.1 to 2.1 (OpenGL version 2.1 INTEL-10.14.66)
the only way stated in the open gl doc is to use `ContextAttribs(3, 2, CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB)`

but for me ContextAttribs can only take 2 arguments, and `ContextAttribs.CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB` either doesn't exist, or is not visible.

I am using LWJGL 2.9.1

I tried googling for ages found nothing that helped me.

How I used to do it before I started using instanced rendering:

```
ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);
```

I have no clue how to do it now, because using `(3,3)` it will start using open gl 2.1 because of MacOSX stuff, my shader programs all used version 330 but of course because of the 2.1 thingy they all get errors.

I wanted to comment on another post, asking for clarification, but because stack overflow requires you to have some reputation, that was not an option :(

Comment: What did you need it for? Have you tried to see if that was available as an third extension?

Comment: I was making a game using lwjgl 2 and wanted to try instanced rendering, before I was using 2,3 but needed to switch to 3,3 for that. but since mac osx does not support it or something, it threw tons of errors.

I tried putting an integer as third argument for ContextAttribs, but since ContextAttribs seems to not have a method with 3 arguments, neither does it have this static final CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB. I have no clue, maybe it would help if I posted my copy of the lwjgl libraries. I don't have a source attached which is unfortunate. maybe should try finding a source somewhere.

Comment: [`glDrawArraysInstanced`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawArraysInstanced.xhtml) and similar requires only GL 3.1

Comment: I am using: GL33.glVertexAttribDivisor(attribute, 1);

Comment: making a particle system that requires a lot of uniform variables, so decided to put it into VBO and VAO's

Comment: It looks [`glVertexAttribDivisor`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribDivisor.xhtml) requires GL 3.2, maybe lwjgl got it wrong, you may want to ask directly them why it is available on `GL33`

Comment: @elect: No, `ARB_instance_arrays` was added in GL 3.3. That docs page is *wrong* and LWJGL is correct.

Comment: Uhm ok, can we correct the docs then?

Comment: cool we are fixing errors but I am still with the problem:
how do I implement instanced rendering on Mac OSX using LWJGL 2.9.1?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164908/opengl-3-3-on-mac-osx-el-capitan-with-lwjgl?rq=1
probably the same problem, but this answers the question for lwjgl 3.0.0 but I am still using 2.9.1 otherwise I need to change 50% of my code.